# Windows PowerShell to Deploy Windows Store Appx Side Loading

Tags: powershell, deployment, windows-store-apps, sideloading, appx

I am currently trying to set my Windows Store app up for side loading.

I have been following instructions such as [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx) but then run into [troubles with a MS Scheme and certificates](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/27b5ff8c-407f-49a3-bbd6-dc95d67f4175/code-signing-issue).

Being unable to get my Code Signing Certificate to work due to the bug in above thread - my next step has been to try and get side loading to work with my app and the certificate that I use with the Windows Store.

My current trouble comes when I try to add the package using Windows PowerShell.

I have the certificate that I signed my app with in the Current User & Local Computer certificate stores under both the Personal & Trusted Root Certificate Authorities certificates.

I have my app file sitting in the current location: C:\Temp\MyApp.appxupload.

Next I enter:

```
add-appxpackage C:\Temp\MyApp.appxupload
```

When I run the command - I receive

```
"Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF0, Package could not be opened."
```

The log contains a bit more information stating:

```
"OpenError: (C:\Temp\MyApp.appxupload) [Add-AppxPackage], FileNotFoundException".
```

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tells me that there are a number of possibilities this error could be:

```
The package couldn't be opened.

Possible causes:

The package is unsigned.
The publisher name doesn't match the signing certificate subject.
The file:// prefix is missing or the package couldn't be found at the specified location.

Check the AppxPackagingOM event log for more info.
```

I don't believe that any of these things are the case, and I wondered if anyone else had had a similar problem and knew how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you use Add-AppxPackage on .appx files and not .appxupload files.  Try renaming the file to a zip file, open up the zip and extract the .appx file. Then run Add-AppxPackage on the extracted .appx file.